# CSS Submenu Align Center in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists, center, submenu

Hi I had to create a horizontal submenu for a website using wordpress. I played around with the CSS and am almost there I just need to align my links in the submenu to the centre. I tried:

`text-align: center;`

In the #access ul ul, But that didn't seem to work :S

The website is: http://dev.timson.me (Submenus on "Upcoming" & "Past Productions")

And the CSS is:

```
#access {
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto 6px;
padding-top: 8px;
width: 100%;
font-family: Stag;
display:block;
text-align:center;
}

#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;

    display:inline-block;
}
#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#access a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#access ul ul {

    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 264px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-left:-500px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

    background: red;
}

#access ul ul a {

    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom:10px;

}

#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated cheers.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add this rule

```
.sub-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Second, change

```
#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

to

```
#menu-default > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

And third, add this rule

```
.sub-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Excellent Thankyou very much! I just found one more thing I need to fix, If you scroll down and then try and use the menu the submenu appears halfway down the page because of:  position: fixed;
    top: 264px; Do you know how to fix this

Comment: Hmm, can't reproduce that one. Sub-menu appears in the right spot in a couple of browsers I tested with.